Are the set of squares (and also higher powers) of positive rationals dense in the positive reals?
Consider the set $S$ of squares of positive rationals. For example, $1/4$ is in $S$, but not $1/2$. I wonder, is $S$ dense in the positive reals? A similar question can be asked for 3rd powers, fourth powers, etc.

If $p_n/q_n \to\sqrt x$ the $p_n^{2}/q_n^{2} \to x$.

Let $x>0.$ Due to the density of the rationals, you can find a sequence of rational numbers converging to $\sqrt{x}.$ Then the squares of these rational numbers will converge to $x.$ So Yes.

@AdamRubinson That should probably be an answer.

I'm not sure I agree with people downvoting your question, but I suspect if I posted my answer it would get downvoted also, so I'm not going to do that unless your question starts receiving upvotes. Sorry...

Yes, and here is a generalisation:

If $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, then $f(\mathbb Q)$ is dense in $f(\Bbb R)$.

Take $f(r)\in f(\Bbb R)$. Take any sequence of rationals $\{q_n\}$ such that $q_n\to r$. Then, $f(q_n)\to f(r)$ by continuity. $\square$
Hope this helps. :)
